# Mobile apps support - All the server version

Tags: design-patterns, mobile-application, mobile-development

I have a mobile-app in stores and my customers have server(web apps + API) in their end. When they are using the app, the user has to enter their server name and login.

My customer have different version(web apps+API) of servers. They will use the common mobile app and does support all the kind of version as of now But We are trying to implement the new features/bug fixing in the mobile app.

While we are releasing the app in store, all the user gets the latest one but some of users unable to use that app(Breaking completely or some of the functionality) because of the following reason

1) They don't have new API in their servers
2) They don't have changes on the existing API in their servers
since we may done some change on the mobile app DB end based on these API or some of the UI fixes alone done(with out change on api and DB)

Our expectation 
The application should work irrespective of all the server version. If they have latest server(Webapps+API), it should show the all the latest fixes or if it is an old, it should so only UI related fixes and need not to show the latest implementation. So what are steps do I need to consider during the development.

After analysis, we have planned to implement the server version checking in the code but we don't know how this way is correct and we are thinking the code may get messy because of these checkes.

Kindly Guide us.